# Using two django model forms on the same view

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `PatientRegistrationForm` and a `PatientBillingForm` form in a single view `RegisterPatient`.

When when I submit the patient form (`form`), the submitted date is stored in the database, nut the billing form (`form1`) only updates the staff and patient fields and nothing is stored in the `payment_type`, `amount` and `receipt_number`.

Please can anyone help point out why the second form is not being updated on the database?

Here is the views, models, forms and template code:

#### views.py

```
def RegisterPatient(request):
    # bills = obj.bill_set.all()

    form = PatientRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    form1 = PatientBillingForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
        instance  = form.save(commit=False)
        instance1 = form1.save(commit=False)

        payment_type = form1.cleaned_data["payment_type"]
        amount = form1.cleaned_data["amount"]
        receipt_number = form1.cleaned_data["receipt_number"]

        first_bill = Billing()
        first_bill.payment_type = payment_type
        first_bill.amount = amount
        first_bill.receipt_number = receipt_number
        # first_bill.saff
        # first_bill.patients
        print first_bill.payment_type, first_bill.amount, first_bill.receipt_number

        first_name = form.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        last_name = form.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        other_name = form.cleaned_data["other_name"]
        phone_number = form.cleaned_data["phone_number"]

        new_patient = Patient()
        new_patient.patient_number = UniquePatientNumber()
        new_patient.first_name = first_name
        new_patient.last_name = last_name
        new_patient.other_name = other_name

        new_patient.save()
        first_bill.save()
```

#### model.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    patient_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique = True, )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    other_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.patient_number

class Billing(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, default=1)
    patients = models.ForeignKey(Patient, default=1)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    receipt_number = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        payment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.staff.username

def new_user_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        new_patient, is_created = Billing.objects.get_or_create(patients=instance)

post_save.connect(new_user_receiver, sender=Patient)

def new_user_creator(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        new_user, is_created = Billing.objects.get_or_create(staff=instance)

post_save.connect(new_user_creator, sender=MyUser)
```

#### form.py

```
class PatientRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        exclude = ["patient_number"]

class PatientBillingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Billing
        fields = ["payment_type","amount","receipt_number"]
```

#### forms.html

```
<form method="POST action="">{% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   {{ form1 }}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: are you sure that `first_bill` is not saved? What if you call `Billing.objects.filter(staff=1,patients=1).last()` ?

Comment: yes bill is not saved because the three fields alway remain empty when viewed from the admin. Again am not sure where am suppose to call   Billing.objects.filter(staff=1,patients=1).last(). thanks

Comment: You can call it in `python manage.py shell` or `print Billing.objects.filter(staff=1,patients=1).last()` after `first_bill.save()` . There you could see how the last Billing entry with same `staff` and `patients`  is changed. If it is changed after each save of `first_bill` please tell me.

Comment: thanks for your response. It printed out admin. that is when i did  hello = Billing.objects.filter(staff=1,patients=1).last().

Comment: what is about `hello.payment_type` , `hello.amount` and `hello.receipt_number` every time after you call `first_bill.save()` ? I mean that I try to understand the logic of this structure that you created. I make an answer below than we can discuss more to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your view function you always create new Billing to `MyUser` with `pk=1` and `Patients` with `pk=1` because you set the default values in Billing fields `default=1`. You should remove `default=1` and set `null=True,blank=True` instead.

If I understand your logic. You want to create new Billing information to every new User oder new Patient. I guess that in your view function you want to update or create Billing information to a patient. If so you should call

`Billing.objects.filter(patients__pk=new_patient.pk).update(payment_type=payment_type,amount=amount,receipt_number=receipt_number)`

after `new_patient.save()` then you could comment out lines with `first_bill`.

---

## Update

1) comment out the line `Billing.objects.filter(...)`

2) comment out `post_save.connect(new_user_receiver, sender=Patient)` in `models.py`

3) activate the lines with `first_bill` again and add:

`first_bill.patients=new_patient` after `new_patient.save()`

Comment: yes but now i have a new error  Unsaved model instance <Patient: UHS1552307> cannot be used in an ORM query.

Comment: ok, please see update.  `patients=new_patient` to `patients__pk=new_patient.pk`

Comment: sorry, please use that: `Billing.objects.filter(patients__pk=new_patient.pk).update(payment_type=payment_type,amount=amount,receipt_number=receipt_number)`

Comment: How do you look up in the database? Do you use django admin interface?

Comment: I update my anwser. Please try and tell me about the result.

Comment: thanks trantu i did this:                                                                                 
try:
   check = Billing.objects.filter(patients__pk=new_patient.pk).update(payment_type=payment_type,amount=amount,
    receipt_number=receipt_number) 

   except:
   pass and it worked